# What are the arguments for considering dynamic links not to constitute derivative works?

Tags: gpl, derivative-works, copyleft, linked-libraries

The status of programs which are dynamically linked with Copyleft licensed binaries (such as a .dll) is contentious. I have created two questions for each side of the debate. The other can be found [here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1187/190).

Unlike the case for considering dynamic links to constitute derivative works, it's been harder to find authorities stating that they do not. But here are some statements saying that there are at least some situations where they do not.

[Linus Torvalds wrote:](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/12/17/79)

> And don't get me wrong: I do not say that "linking" *never* creates 
>   derived works. I'm just saying that "linking" is just a technical step, 
>   and as such is not the answer to whether something is derived or not. 
>   Things can be derived works of each other *without* being linked, and they 
>   may not be derived works even if they *are* linked.
>
> So "linking" basically has very little to do with "derived" per se.
>
> Linking does have one thing that it implies: it's maybe a bit "closer" 
>   relationship between the parts than "mkisofs" implies. So there is 
>   definitely a higher *correlation* between "derived work" and "linking", 
>   but it's really a correlation, not a causal relationship.
>   For example, if you link two object files together where neither is a 
>   "library" with standard interfaces, then the result is most likely a 
>   derived work from both. But it wasn't the "act of linking" that caused 
>   that to happen, but simply the fact that they were part of a bigger whole, 
>   and were meaningless apart from each other.

[The University of Washington's School of Law:](http://www.law.washington.edu/lta/swp/law/derivative.html)

> The results in this example seem to be the same as above. As long as module C(S) is not considered to be a work derived from G, then it is not within the scope of the GPL. If X can distribute C(S) separately from C(G'), and the combination of C(S) and C(G') is only made by the end-user, X should be free to license C(S) under whatever terms she chooses. And the distribution scheme seems a fraction less “kludgey” than the one employed in example 2, because the step of combination (linking) occurs transparently to the user of a dynamically linked system.
>   ...
>   In short, the debate over static and dynamic linking simply misses the mark. As we shall see in our next example, using inter-module communication as the basis for a derivative work analysis will lead frequently to counter-intuitive and nonsensical results.

What are the arguments in support of this position?

Comment: Because you mentioned .dlls (not .so files) I have to bring up a technicality, Visual Studio's linker (not MinGW's linker) can't implicitly link against .dll files, it can only link against .lib files. From what I understand, unless you do `LoadLibrary` (explicit linking) to load the dll you are making a derivative work of the library and the LGPL section 6 triggers (requiring you to release all object files).

Answer (score 20):

While the position of the FSF about the interpretation of the GPL is clear, a [few people have opposed this position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Linking_and_derived_works).

Linus' position that is cited in the OP is, that all combined parts must be meaningless without being part of the combination to form a derivate.

[Matt Asay](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/1532.html) compares linking of software to the act of referencing a character, a scene or something similar from a novel in another novel. He claims as with linking no code is copied, it is not derivative.

Lawrence Rosen [goes even farther](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6366):

> The primary indication of whether a new program is a derivative work
>   is whether the source code of the original program was used, modified,
>   translated or otherwise changed in any way to create the new program.
>   If not, then I would argue that it is not a derivative work.

So, dynamically or even statically linked programs are in this view not always derivates.

But beware, the interpretation if linking is forming a derivative work has not yet (as far as I know) been tested in courts. GPL was topic of quite a few law-suits, but it was never about linking.

Answer (score 16):

This pair of questions (whether dynamic linking creates a derivative or not) is really a false dichotomy.

I think Linus Torvalds is spot on when he says (quoted in the question):

> So "linking" basically has very little to do with "derived" per se.

One problem with this false dichotomy it that leads to reasoning that if dynamic linking, does *not* create a derivative, then something that dynamically links something is not a derivative of that library.  I think that pointing out that this is false reasoning is what is implied in last point in the [University of Washington's School of Law](http://www.law.washington.edu/lta/swp/law/derivative.html)  text quoted by *curiousdannii*:

> On the other hand, if plugins are launched as separate programs, then Fireplug suddenly is not a derivative work, even though this result is counter the common sense result above. Clearly, the mechanism of a given plugin architecture are analytically unhelpful and misleading in answering the derivative work question.

I.e. they are *not* saying that the hypothetical Firefox-derived program is *not* a derivative work.  IMHO, they're saying that it is, but that it unhelpful to use the  "mechanism of a given plugin architecture" to decide whether it is or not.

I think this false dichotomy is not helpful.  I sometimes see the following argument presented:

Since X is dynamically linked, and there is no legal precedence that dynamic linking produces a derivative, we can conclude that the composite that makes use of X is *not* a derivative of X.

I believe this is *not* a valid argument.  That something is dynamically linking is *irrelevant* to deciding whether it is a derivative of X.

Instead, we must determine how the composite *uses* X.  If the composite can not function without X, then the composite is a derivative of X, no matter what mechanism is used to produce the composite.

There is little case law in this area (and AFAIK, none involving FLOSS licenses), but I think the 9th circuit ruling on [Micro Star v. FormGen Inc.](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/people/tfisher/IP/1998%20Micro%20Star%20Abridged.pdf) comes close. The court found that a CD-ROM with files containing fan-curated levels for a video game did create a derivative work when combined with the original game. While the court agreed that the game manufacturer (FormGen) had licensed its *users* to create an share such levels, the infringing company (Micro Star) has not been granted such a license.  The ruling says:

> Nothing indicates that FormGen granted Micro Star any written license at 
>   all;  nor  is  there  evidence  of  a nonexclusive  oral  license.  The  only  written  license  FormGen  conceivably granted was to players who designed their own new levels, but that license contains a significant  limitation:  Any  new  levels  the  players  create  "must  be  offered  [to  others]  solely  for free".
>   The  parties  dispute  whether  the  license  is  binding,  but  it  doesn't  matter.  If  the  license  is  valid,  it clearly prohibits commercial distribution of levels; if it doesn't, FormGen hasn't granted any written licenses at all.

In this case, it is not even a matter of static or dynamic "linking".  The user-curated levels are delivered on a CD in the form of files on a format that is understood by the video game.  One of the things that makes these files a derivative is that these files are not *usable* unless they are read of the original game program. It is not the software mechanism used to create the composite that makes this a derivative work, but the fact that derivative work cannot be separated from the original and still function, that decides the outcome.

I should also make it clear that I think Lawrence Rosen of the OSI is wrong when he [says](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6366):

> When a company releases a scientific subroutine library, or a library of objects, for example, people who merely use the library, unmodified, perhaps without even looking at the source code, are not thereby creating derivative works of the library.

I consider Rosen's argument as politicised, and motivated by his personal belief that open source should be about convenience, not about freedom. Rosen, along with collegue Michael Einschlag writes:

> The real reason you should care about this issue [i.e. what consitutes a derivative work] is that we want to encourage as much free and open source software to be created without scaring proprietary software users away.  If people believe that merely touching your open source software will *infect* their software with a virus, you will make your software less attractive.
>   (Source: http://www.rosenlaw.com/lj19.htm)

I *agree* with Rosen that the exact mechanism you use to make use of the library in you program (static linking, dynamic linking, etc.) does not matter.

However, I *disgree* with Rosen that "merely use" of said scientific subroutine library in a larger work does *not* result in a derivative. I think this is a *lex ferenda* argument. where Rosen wants the law to match OSI's agenda of making the use of free software attractive to commercial companies *including* permitting such companies to make use of free software in products that does not provide the community with *any* freedoms.

Such an interpretation of the law is IMHO wrong, and leads to undesirable situations. For instance, let's assume that the "scientific subroutine library" is made available under GPLv3, and some company use it to as part of some sort of proprietary scientific spreadsheet package.  Without the functions in the GPLv3 library, the spreadsheet would not be *functional*.  This use of the library would at least violate the *intent* of the author of the library, no matter how it is technically combined with other software to create the resulting composite work. (If the library author had intended to permit such uses, he/she would have picked a license that allowed incorporaton of the library in a proprietary work, such as LGPLv2.1.)

IMHO it is *not* the technical architecture of the composite work that is the reason composite should be considered a derivative of the GPLv3 library, but the *functional integration* of the two - i.e. the fact that without the GPLv3 library, the composite work (the proprietary scientific spreadsheet) would simply not work.  This means that if the spreadsheet *depends on* the GPLv3 library, it is this *functional dependency* (and not the technical architecture used to combine the two) that gives grounds to say that the spreadsheet is a derivative of the  GPLv3 library.

Linking is usually done because the functionality linked-in is required, so it is harder to come up with a counter-example (where something is somehow linked, but there is *no functional dependency* between the parts).  But in a highly contrived example, one can think of a library that would replace the standard library `printf` with an alternative version that would redact certain words in the program's output.  The original program is in no way functional dependent on the redacting version of `printf` - linking in the alternative library simply changes the behavior of the program. In this case, even if the library is statically linked, the resulting composite is (probably) not a derivative of it.

So to conclude: We should not *always* conclude that using a dynamically linked library constitutes a derivative work of said library, but the opposite conclusion (that dynamic linking does *not* constitute a derivative work) is equally false.

Comment: I think the last paragraph I quoted in my answer is rather badly phrased, because I don't think a school of law would really try to say that it meant the plugin was entirely non-derivative, that's just too basic an error to make. But bad phrasing is bad phrasing and it does deserve to be criticised.

Comment: Can you cite legal background for ' If the composite can not function without X, then the composite is a derivative of X, no matter what mechanism is used to produce the composite.'? http://www.groklaw.net/article.php?story=20040715212732854 seems to say the precise opposite.

Comment: @bmargulies. The ruling in Micro Star v. FormGen Inc (referenced in my answer) provides such legal background. As for the  The Abstraction-Filtration-Comparison Test discussed in the Groklaw page you refer to, I don't understand how it applies here. IMHO, failing to mention functional interdependence is not the same as saying "the precise opposite".

Comment: The groklaw post seemed to require an actual copy, thus my perplexity.

Comment: @bmargulies. The groklaw post is specifically about the (non-)validity of the claim that Linux infringes on SCO by containing code-snippets that are somehow similar to SCO-copyrighted code. Nobody has argued that Linux cannot function without SCO, so that aspect is naturally not mentioned in this groklaw article.

Comment: I think I see where my education is lacking -- enough of this here.

Comment: @FreeRadical What happens in cases where it is _legally_ possible to make the product functional without the others code. That is, you reuse the API and implement the corresponding functions on your own. I think Oracle vs Google, and the copyrightability of APIs is heavily related to this discussion.

Comment: If the library is statically linked then the compiled program is *trivially* a derivative of the library (because it contains the library). If the library is *dynamically* linked then you have an argument that the compiled program is not its derivative.

Answer (score 6):

[The page from the University of Washington's School of Law goes on to say](http://www.law.washington.edu/lta/swp/law/derivative.html)

> Typical object oriented programming languages include a standard class
> hierarchy. This hierarchy provides a framework within which
> application developers can build their programs. The standard classes
> typically provide useful classes that represent user interface
> elements (e.g. windows, buttons, etc.), collection classes (for
> handling collections of data), and input-output abstractions (e.g.
> files and networking connections). In many object oriented languages,
> each class must be a subclass of exactly one superclass. And for this
> reason, the class hierarchies are rooted by a highly generic, standard
> class called Object. (The question of the superclass of Object is
> beyond the scope of this article.) The class Object describes only the
> most general properties and behaviors. For instance, in Java, the
> class Object only performs a handful of functions. In Java, every
> class is a subclass (directly or indirectly) of the Object class.
> Under the GPL approach, then, every program written in Java is a
> derived work of Object, because every program written in Java by
> definition consists of classes that inherit from the Object class.
>
> Such a result certainly sounds extreme. The Object class in Java is
> extraordinarily generic and bears little relation to many of the
> classes that inherit from it. To be sure, all Java classes can perform
> the behaviors defined by Object, precisely because they are subclasses
> of Object, but this does not necessarily imply that those subclasses
> should be considered derived works under copyright law. It would be as
> if an author writes an incredibly generic, one-sentence long "story"
> along the lines of "There are some characters who do things and stuff
> happens to them" and then claims that just about every novel that
> follows is a work derivative of his story. From a naive perspective,
> almost every story (perhaps with the exception of Waiting for Godot)
> can be considered derivative of our short story because it borrows or
> incorporates the same essential plotline. Obviously, though, this is
> not the result that we obtain under the law. Principally, the reason
> is that the short story would not be considered copyrightable subject
> matter, either because it does not meet the minimum creative
> threshold, or because it is already in the public domain, or because
> the idea of the story has merged with its expression.
>
> As usual, the answer in this example depends on questions of
> copyrightability, incorporation, substantial similarity, market
> demand, and public policy. As a general matter, in the case of
> inheritance in object oriented systems, a subclass trivially
> incorporates (and is substantially similar) to its superclass. The
> analysis should then turn, to a larger degree, on questions of
> copyrightability of the superclass, market demand, and public policy.
> For example, if the class B is highly generic (as in Java's Object
> class), it is unlikely that it would even be considered copyrightable
> subject matter under the 102(b) bar. On the other hand, if B is highly
> specialized—as are classes that we find on the fringes or leaves of a
> class hierarchy—there may be a stronger argument that they contain
> substantial copyrightable subject matter. This argues, then, for a
> finding that D is a derivative of B. Even here, though, a market
> demand analysis might argue against a finding of derivation. Class D
> will not supplant demand for class B, simply because it makes no sense
> to deploy D in the absence of B.

I take this to mean that there is a good argument that subclassing through dynamic links can constitute derivative works, but it depends on what is being subclassed: the base Object class is too generic (and perhaps not even copyrightable), but if you subclassed a large class which represented most of the library then it would count as derived. This makes sense to me.

They address function calls in a different place, arguing that they are not derivative:

> The third factor focuses on the amount of the original work used in the allegedly infringing work. Here, assuming that modern software engineering principles are followed, the amount of literal copying of code in G' is surely minimal. The relationship between S and G' is just that S makes function calls into G'. Therefore, S makes use just of the function names defined by G', and doesn't actually copy any portions of the G's program text. Finally, the market effect analysis also works in X's favor, because S does not supplant the market for G. In fact, anyone who wishes to use S has to also download a copy of G'.

Finally they give a couple of examples of plugins, concluding that the precise method of linking things is the wrong criteria for determining whether something is derivative or not:

> To understand the implications of this method of boundary drawing,
> consider for a moment the Acrobat Reader plugin for Firefox, and
> assume that the browser is licensed under the GPL. The plugin offers
> its own set of user interface buttons and is capable of rendering file
> formats that are exotic to Firefox. Does this seem like a derivative
> work of Firefox? Whatever our intuition may tell us, the answer
> depends - according to the GPL's drafters at least - on the
> particulars of the Firefox plugin architecture. If the plugin
> architecture launches plugins and runs them in separate address spaces
> as separate, running executables, then the GPL does not consider
> Acrobat Reader a derived work of Firefox. On the other hand, if the
> plugin is dynamically linked to Firefox, then the GPL urges the
> opposite characterization. This seems to fly in the face of common
> sense, which tells us that Acrobat Reader is not a work derived from
> Firefox.
>
> The following thought experiment demonstrates the absurdity of the GPL
> approach. Imagine taking the Firefox source code and modifying it in
> such a way that it is encapsulated in a plugin, called Fireplug.
> Common sense and the law tell us that Fireplug is a derivative work of
> Firefox, based simply on the fact that Fireplug incorporates all or
> most of the Firefox codebase. Now, when we plug Fireplug into Firefox,
> we essentially have a Firefox browser running within a Firefox
> browser. And depending on the Firefox plugin architecture, the GPL
> drives us to incompatible results. If plugins are dynamically linked,
> Fireplug is a derivative work. This is the right result, but the
> reasoning is exactly wrong. Fireplug is a derivative work because it
> incorporates and is substantially similar to Firefox, not because of a
> decision made by the designer of the Firefox plugin architecture. On
> the other hand, if plugins are launched as separate programs, then
> Fireplug suddenly is not a derivative work, even though this result is
> counter the common sense result above. Clearly, the mechanism of a
> given plugin architecture are analytically unhelpful and misleading in
> answering the derivative work question.

Comment: That last paragraph doesn't hold up.  UW are assuming that *only* the plugin-closeness test can tell you whether something is a derivative or not, but that's not what the FSF are saying.  Fireplug is a derivative work of Firefox even if it's invoked through fork-and-exec, because the code is entirely taken from Firefox.  Merely invoking it through fork-and-exec doesn't free it from that heritage.   When they write "*if plugins are launched as separate programs, then Fireplug suddenly is not a derivative work*", that is not in fact so, which rather torpedoes their whole argument.

Comment: @MadHatter Maybe. I thought it pretty effectively showed that the plugin architecture question is a red herring. Sharing a memory address space is a pretty bizarre thing for the FSF to make a central diagnostic criteria. (And it's really C-centric.)

Comment: I can't see that it showed that, because its central argument fell flat.  I can see the point they wanted to make, and it would have been a great argument for the uselessness of the linking-as-sole-criterion-of-derivativeness, if anyone was actually saying that.  But since they're not, the whole paragraph, it seems to me, signifies nothing.  Can't speak as to the rest of the article, though.

Comment: @curiousdannii It's a proof-by-contradiction. "If X is true, then Y is true, and Y is obviously really stupid. Therefore it would be really stupid if X was true. Therefore X isn't true."

Answer (score 3):

In section 0 of the GPLv2 license text the meaning of "derivative work" is clarified inside the definition of "work based on the Program":

> This License applies to any program or other work which contains a notice placed by the copyright holder saying it may be distributed
>   under the terms of this General Public License.  The "Program", below,
>   refers to any such program or work, and a "work based on the Program"
>   means either the Program or any derivative work under copyright law:
>   that is to say, a work containing the Program or a portion of it,
>   either verbatim or with modifications and/or translated into another
>   language.  (Hereinafter, translation is included without limitation in
>   the term "modification".)  Each licensee is addressed as "you".

So it seems like "derivative work", in this license, is intended to mean "a work containing the Program or a portion of it". When you link dynamically to a library, your program does not contain the library or any portion of it, other than the names of some symbols. Your program may also use some data structures from the library but that might not count as containing a portion of the library.

GPLv3 does not mention the word "derivative".