# Is linking a correct proxy for derivative work determination in (copyleft) FOSS licenses?

Tags: derivative-works, copyleft, linking

I tend to use these simple tests to determine if the copyleft terms of a third-party project apply to the calling/reusing code:

- if the calling code is linking (statically or dynamically) with GPL-style licensed code, then the copyleft of the callee applies to the caller because the calling code is then a "derivative work" of the GPL-licensed code.
- if the calling code is (statically and not dynamically) linking with LGPL-style licensed code, then the copyleft of the callee applies to the caller because the calling code is then again a "derivative work" of the LGPL-licensed code.

These are simple tests and they seem to be generally accepted in the community. They are easy to apply and to understand technically. Or are they? And I wonder if these are correct tests. Especially linking is something that is well understood for code compiled to native binaries... but what does it mean for interpreted dynamic languages?

So is linking a proper proxy to determine that calling code is "based on" or a "derived work" of the copyleft code being called and that therefore the copyleft flows to the caller?

Answer (score 7):

No-one knows.  It's not the licence, nor the FSF, that determines what constitutes a *derivative work* - it is copyright law.  Since no higher court has (to my knowledge) taken a position on this, we simply don't yet know.  There are [persuasive arguments that it does](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/what-are-the-arguments-for-considering-dynamic-links-to-constitute-derivative-wo?rq=1); there are [persuasive arguments that it doesn't](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1188/what-are-the-arguments-for-considering-dynamic-links-to-not-constitute-derivat?rq=1).  Until courts start to rule on the issues, are appealed to higher courts, and both local and international legal consensus emerges, I don't think *anyone* can say for sure.

To address a possible misconception, **if** dynamic linking with GPL'ed code creates a derivative work, **then** the same is true of dynamic linking with an LGPL'ed work.  The [old LGPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html) was pretty clear about this

> A program that contains no derivative of any portion of the Library,
>   but is designed to work with the Library by being compiled or linked
>   with it, is called a "work that uses the Library" ...
>
> [L]inking a "work that uses the Library" with the Library creates an
>   executable that is a derivative of the Library (because it contains
>   portions of the Library), rather than a "work that uses the library"

No distinction is made there between static and dynamic linking.

Comment: Any special consideration for dynamic interpreted languages vs. compiled-to-binary ones?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  The question of linking two codes bases into an executable can't arise with interpreted languages, so none of this question seems to me to apply.  Also, hi Philippe, glad to see you got back from FOSDEM OK!

Comment: It's a copyright law indeed. See [here](https://mediatechlaw.mstreetlegal.com/2014/04/25/open-source-dynamic-linking-and-licensing-consideration-for-developers) (under the "DERIVATIVE WORK" section). We do know the rough definition of a derivative work. BTW I'm not a legal expert. I would say that dynamic linking is building alongside or using the GPL'd code. And static linking is building on-top-of the GPL'd code which in my opinion makes a derived work.

Answer (score 1):

Linking is a common proxy for whether or not something is a derivative work of a copyleft licensed software project, but in the LGPL case, it doesn't matter whether the linking is static or dynamic - mere linking does *not* create a derivative work.

Instead, you have to make modifications to the source code of the LGPL project itself for it to be counted as a new derivative work, and hence trigger the copyleft provisions.

Comment: I am honoured to see you drop by!

Comment: Indeed, the text of the LGPL calls the linking case a "Combined Work," distinct from a "Modified Work" which actually changes the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

The gcc license provides a very broad and irrevocable license for anyone and everyone to produce derivative works of gcc-licensed materials if those derivative works are not distributed.  It also provides a very broad and irrevocable license for anyone and everyone to distribute authorized collections of files which contain the gcc-licensed works and all applicable source code therefor via wide variety of means including publicly accessible https:// servers.  Further, the license has no authority over works which are not derived from any copyrightable portions of gcc material.

If the recipient of a GPL library and a closed-source library statically links them, the result would be a derived work which could not be distributable under the GPL, but the gcc license grants all the permissions necessary for to link the code if the resulting executable isn't distributed.

If a particular collection of files contains everything necessary to be a standalone authorized distribution of a gcc program or library, the gcc license would grant everyone in the universe, including the creator of a closed-source program that could be usefully linked into an executable that also contained the gcc library, to host those files on a publicly-accessible web server.  Further, a program that would automatically download the open-source library from the web server that contains it would not contain any copyrightable aspects from that open-source code, and would thus not fall under the authority of the GPL.

If the closed-source program were to interact directly with the GPL library directly, there could be some questions about whether it contained any copyrightable aspects of the GPL library within it.  Such a possibility could be disproved, however, by having the creator of the closed-source software publish an open-source "bridge" which communicated with its own API, and demonstrating that the software would work with a bridge that was modified to use a different library that had nothing in common with the GPL one.

The main difference between static linking and dynamic linking is not the technical aspect of how code is loaded at run-time, but rather whether any derived works containing a mix of GPL and closed-source code are distributed.  A program which will dynamically link with a GPL library can be directly executable without containing any copyrightable portion of that library and thus being a derived work thereof requiring a license for distribution.  An executable program which is statically linked with the library, however, would be a derived work, and could thus not be distributed in executable form.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently I don't have enough reputation to comment. Mad hatter is not right.  A clear distinction was made between dynamic and static linking.  That text in the "old" LGPL seems like a big deal.

"[L]inking a "work that uses the Library" with the Library creates an executable that is a derivative of the Library (because it contains portions of the Library), rather than a "work that uses the library""

Yes, that's a distinction.  With static linked code you are actually handing out copies of the GPL work in question. It's in there as part of the executable as described right there. You're distributing someone else's program, and you need permission to do that. With dynamic linking you are distributing work that is 100% your own (well, with a possible question regarding header material).  The user then combines them, and in dynamic linking I'm not even sure you can say that there ever becomes one "executable" that "contains" the GPL code.  That depends what an "executable" means in the context of RAM.  But that's a very different question anyway.  The argument used in *this particular quote* is about actually containing the GPL code, and with dynamic linkage that argument at best becomes a question of what the user does with it, and maybe what the provider intends the user to do with it, but certainly not about someone else's work being contained in the distributed to the user.  It's a huge difference.

It's like if I sell i-phone covers.  Yes, it's useless without an iphone (often not the case with software that needs a library. It loses some functionality but isn't always useless).  I guess it's "derived" from the "interface" of an iphone, directly designed literally its physical interface (shape), but the cover was not made by Apple and it exists and is distributed without Apple. Can apple distribute a license with their phone that says I can't make covers for their phone without those covers being distributed under their license? This is what GPL zealots want to think they should be able to do. And they think if I don't like it I shouldn't make the phone covers.  Do they get to tell me what kind of phone covers I'm allowed to make?

Ok, but cover doesn't use the phone, the phone uses the cover. I'm adding functionality to apple's product not using their functionality.  Well ok, except that argument doesn't fly with GPL.  They are unwilling to let that slippery slope be opened either for fear it will slide too far.

My program is my program.  It may be useless without something else, just as the phone case is.  You may need other programs to make it useful for you. You can re-implement those other programs yourself if you want.  But my software is 100% mine and GPL doesn't tell me  where I can send it. They've got nothing to do with me. The fact that they say otherwise doesn't make it true.

So Mad hatter was probably right that none of this is well defined by courts. But I think common sense says they clearly have a right to limit static linking, and in my opinion clearly don't have a right to limit dynamic linking. It just needs the right lawyer to make the case for code "accessories" not "derived works".  An accessory is useless by itself but is not a derived product.

Comment: Your answer says that I'm wrong, then argues that dynamic linking doesn't create a derivative work.  Firstly, we already have a [question for that](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1188/458), and this isn't it.  Secondly, **that is not what I said above**.  My answer above is agnostic as to whether dynamic linking creates derivatives, and says so.  My specific claim about the GPL/LGPL is that the LGPL contains no special text to exempt dynamic linking from creating derivatives in the event that courts hold it does, cf the 2nd bullet point in Philippe's question.

Comment: @MadHatter: Whether or not dynamic linking creates a derivative work would only be relevant *if the in-memory code image that resulted were distributed*.  If a closed-source program comes with instructions for statically linking it with open-source components, *and that linking step is done by the recipient*, I see no basis for regarding that as any different from the situation where a system dynamically links code as it's loaded.

Comment: @supercat I disagree.  The right to create derivative works is one of the rights controlled by copyright, just as the right to control distribution is another.  Ongoing distribution of the derivative work will *further* violate the rightsholder's copyright, certainly, but a copyright violation has occurred the moment an (unlicensed) derivative work is made.

Comment: @MadHatter: The gnu license explicitly authorizes the production of derivative works provided they are not distributed.

Comment: @supercat I'm sorry, I thought you were claiming that "*whether or not dynamic linking creates a derivative work would only be relevant if the in-memory code image that resulted were distributed*" was **generally** true.  If you're saying that your analysis only holds for GPL-licensed works, then I agree with you, but I also think it's irrelevant - because in most cases I don't think one can lawfully distribute a closed-source program designed to be linked to GPL software by the end-user at run-time.

Comment: @MadHatter: If the closed-source program is not in any way shape or form a derivative work of any GPL code that wasn't written by the author of the closed-source program, what authority would anyone have to forbid it, given that the GPL expressly and irrevocably grants a license to recipients of GPL code to link it with their programs--open source or not--in cases where they do not distribute the linked versions of the code.  Also, even for non-GPL code I would think that someone who lawfully acquires a library that is designed to be statically linked would be entitled to...

Comment: ...form derivative works for their own use *by linking the library in its designed fashion*.  It would be absurd to suggest that someone who bought a rubber ink stamp would be making "illegal copies" of the design if they inked them and pressed them against paper.  Some stamp makers require that anyone wishing to sell the prints thus produced pay licensing fees beyond the cost of the stamps, but sale of an ink stamp at minimum implies the right of the recipient to use it to produce prints for personal use.

Comment: @supercat I know you hold that point of view, because of what you've written elsewhere on OS.SE.  I don't.  But could we please not discuss the point in someone else's answer's comments field?  If you don't like the answers to this question, write your own, and let the community evaluate it.