# Can i use Apache-2.0 in a project licensed as MIT?

Tags: licensing, mit, license-compatibility, apache-2.0

This [link](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-Apache-licensed-source-code-and-redistribute-it-as-MIT-license) tells me not to use MIT under my license when redistributing the Apache 2.0 source code.

Then, if Apache 2.0 or GPL source code is not included, only when specified in the header file and used as a library? (Build file distribution x)

Here's an example:

```
//if something.h is apache2.0 license
#include <something.h>

something.use()
// and this code under mit
```

Comment: Please provide details of what you are trying to do. I am not clear if I fully understand your question.

Comment: @Martin_in_AUT I would like to share a project that uses a library with a GPL license. However, those GPL library codes are not included in the repo. I also do not share programs. I only share the code I wrote, not the GPL library. The user has to find the library from other places on his own to build the program. Should my code itself be GPL in this situation?

Comment: Your question is very similar to several previous questions, like these: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9085/can-i-distribute-non-gpl-code-that-uses-gpl-code-as-long-as-i-dont-distribute-m  and https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/can-i-license-python-project-under-3-clause-bsd-while-it-has-gpl-based-dependenc and https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/can-a-non-gpl-python-program-use-gpl-python-module . Please check if you can find the answer there, or explain what is still open.