# Giving attributions to "inner" open source

Tags: attribution

I developed an application and it's time for me to give the required attribution.

I have a general question. If for example, I use an open-source library called X which uses open source libraries Y and Z, do I need to give attributions to them also or only to X which will direct by itself to Y and Z?

I will give an example. There is an API for android developers called `Including Open Source Notices` that allows you to use it as part of the application and once you build the application, it checks all of the components that are used in it and creates the licenses.

When I use this tool, it gives me licenses such as:

```
Copyright (c) 2005-2011, The Android Open Source Project

Copyright 2014 Google Inc.

Chinese/Japanese Word Break Dictionary Data (cjdict.txt)

UTF-8 Library
```

I mean, it seems to be so much into the program and I never saw that an Android application gives attribution to Android Studio or to the font that the program itself uses. It seems to me like giving attributions to Windows because the computer turned on when I wrote the application.

Thank you

Comment: Your obligations with respect to Y and Z depend entirely on the licences on Y and Z.

Comment: In what way do the libraries "use" each other?  If they're simply runtime dependencies of each other, there's no need for any attribution, as they are not derivative works.

Comment: @jwodder that's not known for certain.  We have two questions here, both of which consider the question of whether dynamic linking generates a derivative work for licensing purposes; one considers answers that say [it does](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1187/458), the other, answers that [it doesn't](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1188/458).  I don't think the question is settled at this time, so unless you know that courts have ruled on it, it might be best not to be quite so prescriptive.