Why would the GPL be "viral", while EUPL isn't, according to the EUPL authors?
So, according to the FSF, any work that links to a GPL licensed work is considered a derivative work, and thus also needs to be covered by the GPL.
The EUPL also demands derivative works to become EUPL licensed, however... they have a different opinion on what constitutes a derivative work:

The licence (or "license" in US spelling) is reasonably (or moderately/weakly) "copyleft" meaning that derivatives works must stay covered by the same licence in case they are distributed to third parties. But the definition of derivative works depends on the applicable law. If a covered work is modified, it becomes a derivative. But if the normal purpose of the work is to help producing other works (it is a library or a work tool) it would be abusive to consider everything that is produced with the tool as "derivative".

(source)
This confuses me a bit. It appears the distinction on what constitutes a derivative work is based on how European law defines it. But... then that would mean that the same applies to GPL, and thus GPL would also no longer be "viral". Since neither GPL nor EUPL specify a definition for derivative work in the license itself.
What am I missing here?

You might be interested in the arguments presented in both https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1188/what-are-the-arguments-for-considering-dynamic-links-not-to-constitute-derivativ and  https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/what-are-the-arguments-for-considering-dynamic-links-to-constitute-derivative-wo

The GPL isn't viral. It's just that if you use code (or anything) written by others, you need to follow the rules of the license you got from them. That goes for any license. Licenses don't jump into your codebase through someone sneezing near it, or anything like that.

@ilkkachu You could say that the vanilla GPL on a library is viral, since the intention is to incorporate that library into another program. The authors of GPL itself would prefer the term "copyleft", though.  The basic idea is to encourage more GPL (or "Free") software and to less proprietary software. For example: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-not-lgpl.html

"But if the normal purpose of the work is to help producing other works (it is a library or a work tool) it would be abusive to consider everything that is produced with the tool as 'derivative'."" So it's basically the LGPL rather than the GPL?

You are not really missing anything.
Open-source licenses are rooted in copyright law in that they give others certain rights that copyright law reserves to the copyright holder (typically, the author). The difference between the various open-source licenses is in the conditions you need to abide by to exercise the rights that the license gives you.
The rights that copyright law protects are the right to make copies, the right to make derivative works and the rights to distribute those. In order to function, copyright law also has to define what is meant by "derivative work".
The big problem is that copyright law was written before software existed and the way it gets applied to software is to treat software as a literary work, like a book.
This means that the definitions that copyright law is based upon do not take certain aspects that are unique to software into account, like combining multiple, independently created works (libraries) into a larger work (application) that is not simply an aggregation of the libraries and the routine automatic transformations that are done (compiling).
As copyright law does not clearly define if an application using third-party libraries is a derived work of those libraries or not, different lawyers can have different opinions on it. And the confusion will remain until enough judges have ruled one way or the other to create a precedent.

Thank you for your answer!
I believe I was already more or less aware of what you said. But where it becomes unclear to me is when the UEPL says "We are different from GPL because XYZ"; while at the same time XYZ also applies to GPL, which makes them identical? (At least in this regard, namely the "viral" aspect).
The way I see it, they're either both viral; or they're both not. Depending on the perspective/jurisdiction/law/...

@Opifex: I would suggest comparing and contrasting the EUPL to the LGPL and the MPL, both of which have explicit clauses that limit the scope of their copyleft in specified ways.

At least by the quoted text (have never heard of EUPL before this), it looks like they are making something closer to the LGPL rather than GPL itself. There may be details that make that belief incorrect, but that is sure what the quoted text makes me think.

You wrote: "And the confusion will remain until enough judges have ruled one way or the other to create a precedent."  Yes, but I would add: "or until a specific legal instrument implements a different level of copyright protection when the Work is a computer program. In EU, this was done by Directive 2009/24. Recitals 10 and 15 are especially recommended for reading."

The text of the GPL is quite explicit that it only applies to works that copyright law considers to be copies of the original work:

To "modify" a work means to copy from or adapt all or part of the work
in a fashion requiring copyright permission, other than the making of
an exact copy. The resulting work is called a "modified version" of
the earlier work or a work "based on" the earlier work.
A "covered work" means either the unmodified Program or a work based
on the Program.

(source, under TERMS AND CONDITIONS a little way down)
And if you think about it even briefly, it's pretty obvious that it can't apply to anything else. If the relevant jurisdiction's copyright law says my work is a derivative work of yours, then without you granting me a licence (that I accept) I cannot distribute my work; if I want to distribute it I need to agree to whatever conditions you offer me to obtain a licence, so I have to care what your licence says. But if copyright law doesn't classify my work to be a derivative work of yours, then I simply don't need a licence from you. In that case it can't matter what terms and conditions are in a hypothetical licence you might offer me; I will simply not accept the license and still be allowed to distribute my non-derivative work, regardless of what the license might try to define as a derivative work.
A copyright licence grants you permissions to do things that copyright law would otherwise forbid. It can impose additional restrictions beyond what copyright law normally would only to the extent that licensees agree to abide by those restrictions in exchange for the permissions granted; a licence is technically a contract that must be voluntarily entered by both parties. But it can't redefine what kinds of work copyright law applies to in the first place, and it can't force those additional restrictions on people who never agreed to the licence. Publishing a license document with your code is offering a contract to anyone willing to accept it, not actually a declaration of rules that automatically apply to everyone.
So any statement from the FSF (or anyone else) about what counts as a derivative work is not actually a licence condition. It's an argument about what they think copyright law classifies as a derivative work (i.e. it's how they would argue a judge should rule if there's a court case). And to a lesser extent you can take it as a statement about what sorts of actions they would consider to be licence infringements and might try to enforce (regardless of what the law actually says, they probably won't sue you if they don't think the law forbids your actions). They presumably also hope to be considered relevant experts in any hypothetical court case where the exact conditions of the GPL are relevant, so that their published statements could be referred to by lawyers in other cases and have some legal influence. But ultimately the FSF cannot define what is a derivative work; that's theoretically set by the definitions in the legislation (which are not perfectly precise, so the rulings of the judges who interpret the legislation also matter). All the FSF can do is make arguments about what they think the definition is, or what it should be.
Likewise, the statement you've quoted from the EUPL page isn't actually saying that their licence is defined to be less viral. The very next sentence after your quote is:

Moreover, European law considers that linking two independent works for ensuring their interoperability is authorised regardless of their licence and therefore without changing it: no "viral" effect.

The authors are claiming the "no viral effect" is a feature of European law (and in the part you quoted they argue that this is a good thing, since they consider it would be "abusive" to use a stricter definition of "derivative work"). It doesn't claim that they have defined their licence to be "less viral" than the GPL.
They do later say under "What makes the EUPL unique?"


The EUPL is not viral: according to the provision of European Law (Directive EC 2009/24 recitals 10 & 15), static and dynamic linking can be implemented with other programs without barriers or conditions. This ensures better legal security compared to licences that are not always operating under European Law.


The headline "the EUPL is not viral" claim is a little misleading if you stop reading there, in my opinion. To my reading, they are claiming that European law rules that source code intended to be linked against other code is not automatically a derivative work of the linked code simply by fact of the intent to be linked (it may be derivative for other reasons, of course). They appear to be saying that the EUPL is written with this operation of European law in mind, and thus provides better legal security (presumably: in the EU) than using a license which is written with a different definition of "derivative work" in mind.
(Do note that copyright law is not identical in all jurisdictions, so it's technically possible for a given work to be derivative of another in some places and times but not in others. What exactly this means for what you can do without a license might be very complicated.)

Thanks! I wasn't sure where you were going with this answer initially, but I think the second half of your answer is indeed a good explanation of what is happening with these two licenses.
So if I understand correctly: the EUPL text is a bit misleading and they are indeed both equivalent in this regard, because it is the local law that defines the "viral aspect", not the license itself.

@Opifex Personally I think you're right that the difference is being oversold and the FSF is incorrect about the consequences of their own license text. I can't see how source code that is intended to be linked against another work could be interpreted as "copy[ing] from or adapt[ing] all or part of the work in a fashion requiring copyright permission", and therefore by the GPL's own definitions it doesn't apply to such source code. (Linking a binary would be a derivative work because it does literally copy, and that would seem to be the case for the EUPL under EU law as well?)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.



So, according to the FSF, any work that links to a GPL licensed work is considered a derivative work, and thus also needs to be covered by the GPL.

This is the FSF's opinion of how copyright law should be interpreted, and it is probably most closely based on U.S. copyright law.  But this should be taken as guidance, not as a provision of the license, and you could even take it as being a little self-serving.  But the FSF doesn't get to decide this.  Judges in jurisdictions where copyright-violation lawsuits involving the GPL are brought have that privilege, and they may even come to different conclusions in different cases and / or different jurisdictions.



it would be abusive to consider everything that is produced with the tool as "derivative".

This is the opinion of the EC body that developed the EUPL.  That is likely to carry some weight when EUPL-violation cases are brought in EU countries, but it is still subject to adjudication.  If the EC wants to ensure that interpretation within the EU then the best way for them to do so is to do as much as they can to ensure that "derivative work" is clearly defined that way in the laws of all EU countries.  Outside the EU, they can employ diplomacy to try to get the same.
Note also that that claim conflates works created via an EUPL-licensed tool, and works that are tightly integrated (by linking, for example), with an EUPL-licensed work.  These are very different cases, and the FSF differs from the EC only with respect to the latter.  Conflating them could be seen as a move calculated to make the EC's assertion seem more plausible.


It appears the distinction on what constitutes a derivative work is based on how European law defines it.

Yes, but it is unclear whether the description provided by the EC reflects how the EUPL (or GPL) will actually be interpreted.

But... then that would mean that the same applies to GPL, and thus GPL would also no longer be "viral". Since neither GPL nor EUPL specify a definition for derivative work in the license itself.

Yes, the EUPL and GPL are both sensitive to the local definition of "derivative work", in pretty much the same way.
But no, this does not modulate whether either license is "viral". That designation describes exactly that they require derivative works to be licensed under the same license.  That does not depend on the fine details of what is or is not considered a derivative work in any particular jurisdiction.
Regardless of whether linking to a library makes a program a derivative of that library, both the GPL and the EUPL are appropriately described as "viral" in any jurisdiction where copyright law provides protection against making unauthorized partial copies or modified copies or similar ("derivatives") of protected works.  To the best of my knowledge, that includes at least all countries that subscribe to the Berne Convention (181 of them).

"the distinction on what constitutes a derivative work is based on how European law defines it. But... then that would mean that the same applies to GPL, and thus GPL would also no longer be "viral"...
On this specific point I believe that there is a difference: the application of the EUPL must always be done according to the European law (even if the judge in charge of the case could be outside the EU, for example in UK, US or Switzerland). This EU law includes specific considerations on software interoperability and linking (i.e. recitals 10 and 15 of Directive 2009/24) that are ignored in general copyright regulations, that are based on the Bern Convention. This is not the case with the GPL where the applicable law is ?

Got a source on that? Because most other people say that the local law still applies?

EUPLv1.2 s15 contains a choice of jurisdiction provision.  Such provisions are very common in non-free licences, and I've not heard any serious suggestion that they're somehow invalid on their faces.

If we take the example of a software library, then we have three distinct entities:

(A) The software library itself.
(B) A larger program that is dynamically or statically linked to the software library A.
(C) Another program that is not linked (either statically or dynamically) to either A or B, but communicates with B through inter-process communication.

GPL defines B as a "work based on" A, or a "work derived from" A, when applying copyright law.
In GPLv3, a "covered work" is defined as either "either the unmodified Program or a work based on the Program," and the "Corresponding Source" of a "covered work" is defined to include the source code, build scripts and install scripts of all linked subprograms and libraries, except "System Libraries".
On the other hand, C is considered an aggregate of A and B. C is not derived from B, as defined in GPL.
In GPLv3, an "aggregate" includes works "which are not combined with it such as to form a larger program".
Basically in Linux, FreeBSD, QNX and such similar OS, a software library is included in the memory address space of a user process and its functions or procedures can be called from within the process. The process as a whole is a larger program based on the software library. The GPL applies in a viral manner to the source code of the whole user process, excluding system libraries.
On the other hand, another process, with a separate memory address space, is considered an aggregate by GPL, and the GPL does not apply in a viral manner to the source code of aggregated processes that communicate with the GPL-licensed process through inter-process communication.
Copyright law defines concepts that applies to all kinds of things, not just software. But the GPL, in the context of software, applies the legal definition of  "derivative" or "adaptation" to the technical details, by way of technical definition in the text of the license.
The licensee becomes subject to the conditions and definitions of the GPL, by using and distributing the software licensed under GPL.
We can contrast this to the Apache License v2.0, which states (as quoted below) that it does not consider use of an unmodified Apache-licensed software library (linked statically or dynamically) through its library interfaces, as creating a derivative work.

For the purposes of this License, Derivative Works shall not include
works that remain separable from, or merely link (or bind by name)
to the interfaces of, the Work and Derivative Works thereof.

When it comes to weak copyleft licenses like EUPL, LGPL and MPL, the license conditions of A will not apply to B.
But even here, the technical definitions in those license texts with respect to how A and B are separated, is important.
MPL2 restricts its conditions to individual files of A. It's a file-level copyleft license.
LGPLv2.1 restricts its conditions to a separation by static and dynamic linking. But even here it's tricky when it comes to C++ templates. So, any larger program using a C++ template header library licensed under LGPLv2.1 would become virally affected too. For this reason, GCC's C++ STL project did not choose to use LGPLv2.1.
So, my point here is that the technical definitions in the respective licenses are important in the application of copyright law, and become binding upon the licensee.

I looked up the EU law in question, and it appears to have nothing to do with EUPL or GPL or the "viralness" of an open source software license.
All it says is that a licensee (or someone authorized by the licensee), may perform reproduction and/or translation of the licensed software, in order to make it interoperable with other software, regardless of the license of the licensed software, and this shall not be considered copyright infringement.
Clause 1(b) of Article 6 of EU Directive 2009/24/EC states that this only applies if "the information necessary to achieve interoperability has not previously been readily available". Since EUPL and GPL are open source software licenses, they make all information necessary to achieve interoperability. Hence, Article 6 of EU Directive 2009/24/EC is not applicable to both licenses.
From EU Directive 2009/24/EC:

Article 6 - Decompilation

The authorisation of the rightholder shall not be required where reproduction of the code and translation of its form within the
meaning of points (a) and (b) of Article 4(1) are indispensable to
obtain the information necessary to achieve the interoperability of an
independently created computer program with other programs, provided
that the following conditions are met:

(a) those acts are performed by the licensee or by another person having a
right to use a copy of a program, or on their behalf by a person
authorised to do so;
(b) the information necessary to achieve interoperability has not
previously been readily available to the persons referred to in point
(a); and
(c) those acts are confined to the parts of the original program which are
necessary in order to achieve interoperability.

The provisions of paragraph 1 shall not permit the information obtained through its application:

(a) to be used for goals other than to achieve the interoperability of the
independently created computer program;
(b) to be given to others, except when necessary for the interoperability
of the independently created computer program; or
(c) to be used for the development, production or marketing of a computer
program substantially similar in its expression, or for any other act
which infringes copyright.

In accordance with the provisions of the Berne Convention for the protection of Literary and Artistic Works, the provisions of this
Article may not be interpreted in such a way as to allow its
application to be used in a manner which unreasonably prejudices the
rightholder's legitimate interests or conflicts with a normal
exploitation of the computer program.



"In GPLv3, an "aggregate" does not include works" I think you meant "includes" here.

@ecm Thanks for the correction
